# Jquery code duplication

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Viewing code at: http://jsfiddle.net/bcot/DfVBG/7/

Here, the Jquery is delivered all the required functions.  However, the Jquery code is almost duplicated twice currently(slightly different).

Assume that if it will be changed from Day1 to Day10, So the Jquery code
has to be duplicate 10 times.

Is there anyone can help me to refine the code?

Many thanks

Comment: why would you duplicate the code 10 times ? If you have an event that should be triggered on clicked on one of your input fields simply add a class to your input fields, and then listen for events, happening on that class and then do your coding.

Comment: Your code is like so hard to read, bit of a mess to be honest...Don't know where to start.

Comment: Here's a pointer in the right direction: http://jsfiddle.net/DfVBG/5/ But your HTML is still a fair bit of a mess. Remember, ID's can only be used ONCE, and if you want to use the same code for multiple things, use classes instead of ID's.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use clone? it will clone html as well as vent and all..
refer this http://api.jquery.com/clone/